# Nilpotent elements in group algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Suppose $FG$ -- is group algebra and $F$ is field with characteristic $p>0$. $G$ - is finite $p$-group. Thus, it's clear that $(e-g)$ is nilpotent. But how to show that $(e-g)g_1$ is nilpotent for any $g,g_1 \in G$?

Many thanks in advance!!

Comment: Are we sure this question has a positive answer? Where did it come from?

Comment: it's true with assumption that $G$ - is finite, and $p$-group. It came from my home task.  Exactly, i need to proove that ideal of $FG$ generated by $<e-g>$ is nil ideal in such conditions as i said above..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a more general way to go about this.  Consider the *augmentation map* $\varepsilon:FG\to F$ defined by $\sum_{g\in G} a_gg\mapsto \sum_{g\in G} a_g$ for $a_g\in F$, which is a ring homomorphism.  The kernel $\mathcal{A}_G\subset FG$ of this map is called the *augmentation ideal*.    One can show that $\mathcal{A}_G$ is nilpotent when $G$ is a finite $p$-group and $F$ is characteristic $p$.  This handles your particular problem because $e-g\in\mathcal{A}_G$ for all $g\in G$.

Carlson in Proposition 1.2 (link below) does induction on $|G|$.  When $|G|=p$, then $G$ is a cyclic group, and $\mathcal{A}_G$ has $(e-x,e-x^2,\dots,e-x^{p-1})$ as an $F$-module basis.  Because $G$ is commutative in this case, it is easy to check that $\mathcal{A}_G^p=0$ (using the binomial theorem).

Otherwise, there is a $p$-Sylow subgroup $H$ of $G$.  Let $\sigma:G\to G/H$ be the quotient, and let $\theta:FG\to F(G/H)$ be the induced (surjective) ring homomorphism.  The augmentation map $\varepsilon_G:FG\to F$ factors as $\varepsilon_G=\varepsilon_{G/H}\circ\theta$.  Letting $I=\ker\theta$, we see that $I\subset\mathcal{A}_G$, and also $\theta(\mathcal{A}_G)=\theta(\ker \varepsilon_G)=\theta(\ker (\varepsilon_{G/H}\circ\theta))=\ker \varepsilon_{G/H}=\mathcal{A}_{G/H}$.  By induction, $\mathcal{A}_{G/H}^p=0$, and so $\mathcal{A}_G^p\subset I$.  It suffices to show that $I$ is nilpotent.

Let $x\in G\setminus H$, giving $G=\bigcup_{i=0}^{p-1}x^iH$.  For any $a\in FG$, we may then write it as $a=\sum_{i=0}^{p-1}\sum_{h\in H}a_{x^ih}x^ih=\sum_{i=0}^{p-1}x^i\left(\sum_{h\in H}a_{x^ih}h\right)$.  And if $a\in I$, then $\theta(a)=0$, so $0=\sum_{i=0}^{p-1}\sigma(x)^i\left(\sum_{h\in H}a_{x^ih}\right)$.  The only way for this quantity to be zero is for $\sum_{h\in H}a_{x^ih}=0$ for each $i$, and so $\sum_{h\in H}a_{x^ih}h\in\mathcal{A}_H$.  It follows that $I\subset FG\cdot\mathcal{A}_H$, and in fact $I= FG\cdot\mathcal{A}_H$ because $\mathcal{A}_H$ is the kernel of $\theta$.

One can check that $I^n=(FG\cdot\mathcal{A}_H)^n=FG\cdot\mathcal{A}^n_H$ by induction by playing with elements, and thus since $\mathcal{A}_H$ is nilpotent, so is $I$.  Therefore $\mathcal{A}_G$ is nilpotent.  (And therefore $(e-g)g_1$ is nilpotent for any $g,g_1\in G$.)

Reference: [Carlson, Modules and Group Algebras. Proposition 1.2.](https://books.google.com/books?id=a-EFCAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA3&ots=3v3Nzzi0n5&dq=group%20augmentation%20ideal%20nilpotent%20p%20group&pg=PA3#v=onepage&q=group%20augmentation%20ideal%20nilpotent%20p%20group&f=false%22Modules%20and%20group%20algebras,%20proposition%201.2%22)

A consequence of this fact is that $FG$ is a local ring with unique maximal ideal $\mathcal{A}_G$.  This is because it is maximal from being the kernel of a homomorphism to a field, and because by being entirely nilpotent elements, it is contained inside every other maximal ideal.

(Edit: old answer was nonsense.)

Comment: @rschwieb I replaced answer with a correct argument.  More general than I'd like.  I'm curious if there exists a more straightforward path, but I imagine it will still require induction on $p$-Sylow subgroups.

Comment: Interesting! I have not seen this reference before.